# Slope, aspect and beam in R.Sun (GRASS)

Tags: grass-gis, remote-sensing

I'm starting to mess about with the solar radiation packages of GRASS and ArcGIS and have become rather stuck on the GRASS side of matters. I have a DSM area, and that is feeding into GRASS well enough, however when processing on the default values it falls over, not outputting anything. I'm using the command...

```
g.region rast=elevation.dem
r.sun -s elev=elevation.dem day=180
r.colors col=grey
d.his i_map=beam_map h_map=elevation.dem
```

In the [R.Sun man page](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/manuals/html64_user/r.sun.html), the following command is recommended:

```
g.region rast=elevation.dem
r.sun -s elev=elevation.dem slop=slope asp=aspect beam=beam_map day=180
r.colors beam_map col=grey
d.his i_map=beam_map h_map=elevation.dem
```

However here, where am I supposed to get the slope, aspect and beam from?

Answer (score 4):

'Beam' is output.  'Slope' and 'Aspect' should be computed from the DEM.  For details, follow the link at the bottom of the R.sun man page to the [R.Slope.Aspect man page](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/manuals/html64_user/r.slope.aspect.html).